# wordpress how to convert htaccess to web.config

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web-config

hello guys i have a wordpress multisite that hosted in iis how can you convert htaccess code to web.cofig?

Example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

how to add that in my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

can you help me with this one guys please.. T_T

Comment: So you want to redirect your non www domain to www. Add the rule above "WordPress Rule 1": `<rule name="non-www-to-www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.org$" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.org/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>` . You may find my WordPress web.config for reference here: https://www.saotn.org/my-wordpress-web-config/

Comment: how to do that into www to non-www?

Comment: The exact opposite of course: change the pattern to  `pattern="^www.example\.org$"` and URL to `url="http://example.org{R:1}"`